# BeautifulSoup to scrape multiple link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape this [website](https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Companies?a=#) by using BeautifulSoup, by first extracting every links, then opening them one by one. Once they are opened, I want to scrape the company name, it's tickers, stock exchange and extract the multiple PDF links whenever they are available. It will write them out in a csv file afterwards.

To make it happen, I first try that way :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

source_code = requests.get('https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Companies?a=#')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'lxml')
data = []
links = []
base = 'https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk'

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    data.append(str(link.get('href')))
    print(link)
    try:
        for link in links:
            url = base + link
            req = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
            for j in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
                print(j)
    except:
        pass
```

As far as I know, this website doesn't forbid scraper. But while it actually gives me every links, I'm unable to open them, which doesn't allow me to keep my scraper going for the following tasks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are changing the `soup` object right in the middle of iterating through it.  You need to extract all of the links into a list first, and only then start fetching those links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to iterate over all company links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Companies?a=#"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

links = [
    "https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk" + a["href"]
    for a in soup.select('a[href^="/Company"]')
]

for link in links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")

    name = soup.select_one("h1").get_text(strip=True)
    ticker = soup.select_one(".ticker_name")
    if ticker:
        ticker = ticker.get_text(strip=True)
    else:
        ticker = "N/A"

    # extract other info...

    print(name)
    print(ticker)
    print(link)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
3i Group plc
III
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/3i-group-plc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3M Corporation
MMM
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/3m-corporation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAON Inc.
AAON
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/aaon-inc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABB Ltd
ABB
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/abb-ltd
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Abbott Laboratories
ABT
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/abbott-laboratories
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Abbvie Inc
ABBV
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/abbvie-inc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Abercrombie & Fitch
ANF
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/abercrombie-fitch
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABM Industries, Inc.
ABM
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/abm-industries-inc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Acadia Realty Trust
AKR
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/acadia-realty-trust
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Acciona
N/A
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/acciona
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCO Brands
ACCO
https://www.responsibilityreports.co.uk/Company/acco-brands
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```